# MKV / Transcoding Support from NAS

Tags: video

Most high-end video is encoded in h.264 and distributed in mkv containers. However, support is rather muted and limited to rather pricey apps for now. What are the limitations causing the lack of mkv support (since h.264 mp4s are supported) and native transcoding?

I have a Synology NAS that provides its DS suite of WP8 apps including DS Video. Unfortunately, Synology chose to include pre-streaming transcoding only for their higher-end models. Mine leaves it to the device and Android has no trouble with various apps that handle mkv fine, but my WP simply throws a "codec not supported error". Considering that the video stream that's in h.264 is indeed supported, I'm not sure why it's difficult to just include the container as well? Anyone know of workarounds with DS Video or alternate apps?

Comment: How does your question actually relate to NAS rather than just support for MKV on Windows Phone?

Comment: The second part got lost. Added it back.

Comment: It seems like you have two related, but ultimately different questions. 1. Is MKV supported 2. Streaming from a Synology NAS. So I think it would be best to split it into two different questions, sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone does not support that container and only [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_VideoSupport):

> 3GP, 3G2, WMV, MP4, M4V, AVI and MOV

It doesn't support MKV as they simply haven't decided to support it (for whatever reason). As you have noticed, there are 3rd party apps that do support it, so there is no technical reason why the Windows Phone team hasn't added support.